# Excel formula returns all zeros or !REF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that contains a list of cities and counties.  in this column i need to add a phrase at the end of a cell if it contains the phrase "county".  If not i need to add "city" after.

```
column a 
----------   
denver    
jefferson county
```

the formula im using is

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("county",A1)), A1 & " ABC", (A1& " City"))
```

"denver" should become "denver city"

and

"jefferson county" should become "jefferson county ABC"

Comment: @ScottCraner this formula has worked for me before on other files or  sheets.  However all i get are 0 or !REF.  Is this a procedure issue.  Are you selecting a column then usint ctrl + enter.

Comment: You could do `=If(Right(a1,6)="county",[whatever you want to do with a county],a1 & " city")`

Comment: Why would I use Ctrl-Enter?  You would put this in the first cell then you would copy/drag it down the dataset.  see:  http://imgur.com/a/61bvW

Comment: @ScottCraner your post on imgur reminded me that the formula needs to run in a seperate column not the same one.  Post that as an answer and i will give you credit.  Ctrl + enter (after selecting whole column) is a shortcut so you dont need to scroll down many thousands of cells.